# Batch Empty - enter - space. If I use any of them Its not going to the correct label

Tags: batch-file

```
set "option="
set /p "option= Here=" 

::This is the part that is not working 
if %option% EQU () (goto :MyLabel)
if %option% EQU [] (goto :MyLabel)
IF [%1] == [] GOTO MyLabel
```

Every time that I write in the batch file it kicks me out with a anexpected error. I am trying to make an script that if the user click enters or space enter. It sends me back to the label. Please help.
I have tried with everything on the web but I can find the solution.

I am very new with this.

---

This is all the code that I have:

```
@echo off
:mylabel 

@Echo only d .
set "option="
set /p "option= Here=" 
if %option% EQU d (goto :mylabel)
if %option% EQU "" (goto :mylabel)
if "%option%" EQU "" (goto :mylabel)
if "option" EQU "" (goto :mylabel)
IF "%1"=="" GOTO mylabel

-------------
:menu
set "option="
set /p "option= Here="  
if "%option%" EQU "" (goto :menu)
if %option% EQU c (goto :c)
:c
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
:menu
set "option="
set /p "option= Here=" 
if "%option%" EQU "" (goto :menu)
if %option% EQU c (goto :c)
:c
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is going to be with the `(` `)` chars as they would be unexpected where you are using them (in an empty value). Instead use quotes to do the comparision.

```
REM It appears some code is missing, so only updating what I can see.

set /p "option=Here:"

REM Check for empty with quotes.
if "%option%" EQU "" goto :MyLabel
IF "%~1" == "" GOTO MyLabel
```